# Compare two Child Nodes in XSLT2

Tags: c#, xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT2. We have a requirement to create device history table from XML. Column of table depicts change in device data. We should highlight the value changed between two device history column. How do we compare child nodes and highlight the difference n xslt2 .

Any help would be appreciated

XML File ( here id2 should be bold to indicate the difference).

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DeviceHistory.xsl"?>
<DeviceHistory>
  <Part Name="xyzz">
    <Details>
      <Date>08-04-2019</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Id1:459800800691
        id2:000007</DeviceInfo>
    </Details>
     <Details>
      <Date>08-04-2019</Date>
      <DeviceInfo>Id1:459800800691
        id2:000008</DeviceInfo>
    </Details>
  </Part>
</DeviceHistory>
```

XSL File:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/DeviceHistory">
    <html>
        <body> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Part"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Part">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Details">
              <td class='FRUVal' valign='middle' width='380'> 
                <table>
                    <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="Date"/></tr>
                    <tr ><xsl:apply-templates select="DeviceInfo"/></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can certainly use e.g. `Details[1]/DeviceInfo = Details[2]/DeviceInfo` to compare the two elements in XSLT/XPath. As for finding the part that is different, is the content of a DeviceInfo sn arbitrary string? Or does it follow some pattern like a whitespace separated list of e.g `idx:numericvalue`?

Comment: Content of DeviceInfo is a arbitrary string and doesnot have any pattern

Comment: The only difference is the last digit, the `7` versus `8`, no? I have tried to implement that in XSLT 3 at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6k/1, available for C# and the .NET framework through Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE from NuGet.